# Ruby gsub '<' and '>'

Tags: ruby, regex

Say I have this text:

```
foo
{% highlight ruby %}
bar < >
{% endhighlight %}
```

How do I replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` inside `{% highlight ruby %}...{% endhighlight %}`? I'm also replacing `{% highlight ruby %}...{% endhighlight %}` with `<pre><code class="language-ruby">...</code></pre>` using this:

```rb
str.gsub(/\{% highlight (\w*) %\}(.*)\{% endhighlight %\}/m, '<pre><code class="language-\1">\2</code></pre>')
```

Comment: Did you try `str.gsub(/</m, '&lt;').gsub(/>/m, '&gt;')`?

Comment: Erm, sorry. I forgot to mention I'm replacing only the `<` and `>` inside `{% highlight ruby %}...{% endhighlight %}`.

Comment: What you're talking about doing is basically parsing the document, which is very hard to do with regular expressions.  Instead of doing your own homemade markup language, use either HTML or Markdown.

Comment: Oh yeah. The file I'm actually trying to convert is a markdown file. Right now I have files like [this](https://github.com/dsdeiz/dsdeiz.github.com/blob/master/_posts/blog/2010-02-09-current-xmonad-setup.md). I'm trying to convert this so [Nanoc's colorize filter](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/api/3.4/Nanoc/Filters/ColorizeSyntax.html) can read it. The code blocks need to be changed to `<pre><code class="language-ruby">...</code></pre>` and at the same time convert those `<` and `>` inside those code blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? You're not the first person wanting to create their own markup language, but there are some pretty awesome ones out there. I personally like [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) which has a great ruby implementation called [RedCarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) from the folks over at Github. You can easily parse text with this gem. Here's some example code:

```
require 'redcarpet'

input = <<-EOF
foo

    bar < >
EOF

Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML).render(input)
#=> <p>foo</p>
#=>
#=> <pre><code>bar &lt; &gt;
#=> </code></pre>
```

You may have noticed, that Stack Overflow uses Markdown for user input, so i am actually writing my answer in Markdown right now ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using Redcarpet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using gsub and no external libraries, this will work:

```
str.gsub(/</, "&lt;").gsub(/>/, "&gt;")
```

Or to only match outside of your `{%...%}` markup:

```
str.gsub(/(?<=%}|\A)(.+?)(?={%|\z)/) do |n|
  n.gsub(/</, "&lt;").gsub(/>/, "&gt;")
end
```

The longer regex above uses the lookbehind and lookahead assertions (`(?<=%}|\A)` and `(?={%|\z)`) to only find substrings that are outside of the brackets.

But, the best way would probably still be to use the HTMLEntities gem, since it will always be clearer what you are doing.

```
require 'htmlentities'
HTMLEntities.new.encode(str)
```

or

```
str.gsub(/(?<=%}|\A)(.+?)(?={%|\z)/) do |n|
  HTMLEntities.new.encode(n)
end
```

Comment: Erm, sorry. I forgot to mention I'm replacing only the `<` and `>` inside `{% highlight ruby %}...{% endhighlight %}`.